# Php container does not start in docker

Tags: php

When I run docker-compose, I get an error:

```
php_1       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
php_1       | Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
php_1       |
php_1       |
php_1       |   [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
" is not defined.
php_1       |
php_1       |   Did you mean this?
php_1       |       update
php_1       |
php_1       |
php_1       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
: not found | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 5: exec: php-fpm
```

I tried to restart the docker, delete the containers and restart, but nothing helps

docker-entrypoint.sh code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

composer update

exec "$@"
```

I used to use ubuntu, now I have installed windows and now I get this error. 
Please tell me how I can solve this problem, I have spent more than 3 hours and no result (

Comment: Can you check the content of the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script? This looks like a syntax problem in there. Or possibly it uses an environment variable that is not set to the correct value.

Comment: I'll add one second

Comment: I added, you can watch

Comment: Thanks, yes indeed Windows moved the line

Answer (score 1):

The error "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found", together with the content of the docker-entrypoint.sh script (which contains only a blank line at 2) indicates that the line endings are corrupted.

You should make sure that the files used by the container have UNIX line endings (\n) rather than Windows line endings (\r\n).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run `dos2unix` on script file whenever anyone edit anything on any kind of editor on Windows to convert the line endings, (recommended) remove dos2unix from the machine.

In your case:

```
# add this line after FROM line
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
RUN dos2unix /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix
# --> continue your ./docker/php/Dockerfile content
```

Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55470819/7596401