# How to seed a docker container in Windows

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I intended to install a mongodb docker container from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo), and then insert some data into it. Obviously, a mongodb seed container is needed. So I did the following:

1. created a `Dockerfile` of Mongo seed container in `mongo_seed/Dockerfile` and the code in `Dockerfile` is the following:

   ```
   FROM mongo:latest
   WORKDIR /tmp
   COPY data/shops.json .
   COPY import.sh .
   CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source import.sh"]
   ```

   The code of `import.sh` is the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ls .
   mongoimport --host mongodb --db data --collection shops --file shops.json
   ```

   the `shops.json` file contains the data to be imported to Mongo
2. created a `docker-compose.yml` file in the *current working directory*, and the code is the following:

   ```
   version: '3.4'
   services:
     mongodb:
       image: mongo:latest
       ports: 
       - "27017:27017"
       container_name: mongodb 
     mongodb_seed:
       build: mongodb_seed
       links:
       - mongodb
   ```

The code above successfully made the `mongodb` service execute the `import.sh` to import the json data - `shops.json`. **It works perfectly in my Ubuntu. However, when I tried to run command `docker-compose up -d --build mongodb_seed` in Windows, the import of data failed with errors logs:**

```
Attaching to linux_mongodb_seed_1
mongodb_seed_1  | ls: cannot access '.'$'\r': No such file or directory
: no such file or directory2T08:33:45.552+0000  Failed: open shops.json
mongodb_seed_1  | 2019-04-02T08:33:45.552+0000  imported 0 documents
```

Anyone has any ideas why it was like that? and how to fix it so that it can work in Windows as well?

Comment: Are you running Linux containers on Windows?

Comment: is it possible to get rid of install.sh and put all in CMD? You can also override the CMD in your docker-compose (command: ...)

Comment: I think so, but I don't know how the `WORKDIR` and `COPY` command in the `Dockerfile` of Mongo seed works. I downloaded the mongo docker image from the link [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo), and checked that this mongo docker image is indeed Linux

Comment: The issue is probably that import.sh has now Windows-style line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the error `ls: cannot access '.'$'\r': No such file or directory`.

One of the issues with Docker (or any Linux/macOS based system) on Windows is the difference in how line endings are handled.

Windows ends lines in a carriage return and a linefeed `\r\n` while Linux and macOS only use a linefeed `\n`. This becomes a problem when you try to create a file in Windows and run it on a Linux/macOS system, because those systems treat the `\r` as a piece of text rather than a newline.

Make sure to run `dos2unix` on script file whenever anyone edit anything on any kind of editor on Windows. Even if script file is being created on Git Bash don’t forget to run `dos2unix`

```sh
dos2unix import.sh
```

See https://willi.am/blog/2016/08/11/docker-for-windows-dealing-with-windows-line-endings/

In your case:

```
FROM mongo:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dos2unix
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY data/shops.json .
COPY import.sh .
RUN dos2unix /import.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source import.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change line endings to UNIX in your script file.